# How to create a toggle box using Angular Material?

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to make a toggle box similar to the one you use in the Angular Material docs when you want to view the source code.  You press the <> button on the menu bar and the panel slides open underneath revealing the html.  For example, this page has one: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button

I can't seem to find it anywhere in the docs and I am not sure what the element is called or how to use it.

Comment: For a start, try looking at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/docs/app/partials/docs-demo.tmpl.html) of the `docs-demo`

Comment: & the [source code](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/docs/app/js/demo.js) for the `docs-demo` directive